# Play Framework 1.2.7 mysterious error with form

Tags: html, playframework, playframework-1.x

So I have a form with a submit button and a hidden field. The hidden field holds the value which will be used to query. When the user presses the submit button, the value is supposed to pass to the controller and the controller is supposed to query and then render a new page with the query result. Here is the code,

```
#{list items:courses, as:'course'}
<li>
    ${course.CourseCode}  
    #{form @Courses.detail()}
    <div>
         <input type="text" name="Code" value = ${course.CourseCode} />
    </div>
    <div>
         <input type="submit" value="Course Detail" /> 
    </div>
    #{/form}
</li>
<br />
#{/list}
```

I was having problems with "Course" not found so I changed the hidden field to text. This is where the weird thing starts. I see only half the value of `${course.CourseCode}`. For example, if course code = ICCS 101, I see "ICCS 101" in the list but in the text field I see only ICCS. I have no idea why this is happening.

Here is my controller

```
public static void detail(String Code){
    System.out.println(Code);
    List<Course> courses = Course.find("byCourseCode", Code).fetch();
    int index = courses.size()-1;
    if(index>=0){
        Course course = courses.get(index) ;
        render(course);
    }
    else{
        notfound();
    }
 }
```

Edit::It seems like it truncates everything after the first white space.

Answer (score 1):

In your view the **value** property of your **input** tag should be between quotes **"..."** otherwise everything after the first space will get truncated

```
<input type="text" name="Code" value="${course.CourseCode}" />
```